# How to show unread email count next to collapsed account?

Tags: thunderbird, addons

As I have many email accounts in my Thunderbird side panel, I have to scroll if I'd like to see all accounts in expanded state. Many of these accounts rarely receive emails so it would be ok to collapse them. However in collapsed state, I can't see the unread email count. This leads to another problem because after each time I checked for emails for all accounts, I have to expand all my rarely used accounts again.

Now I'm looking for a solution like this:

[image: example]

The questionmark in the red brackets would be replaced with the unread email count. Do you know any addon which is able to do that? Or do you know any other solution which might help to organize many, rarely used mail accounts?

Comment: For these accounts, do the unread emails all reside in the inbox of the respective accounts?  Also, have you tried View/Folders/Unified?

Comment: Exactly, they reside in the inbox of the respective accounts. View/Folders/Unified doesn't help because there isn't such an indicator either.

Comment: How about marking all your folders that you want to see counts for, and using view/folders/favorites?

Comment: This behavior seems to be now the default of Thunderbird, so the question may not apply anymore.